# AWS Cognito Identity user ID or User Pool user ID? Which to use?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm a bit confused on which ID to use for the following purpose:

There is an online book store with books and users. Each user can have many books. Books are stored in a DynamoDB table alongside with their user IDs associated to them.

Question is, which user ID to be used? Pool user ID or Identity user ID? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the users to be able to read and write directly to the table you need to use the identity pool ID, because that's what's in the authentication context when IAM evaluates the request.

If that's not the purpose and you just want to keep track of the users for internal purposes it might be easier to use the user pool ID. With the user pool ID you can look up user attributes etc., which is not the case with identity pool IDs.

Another way of saying this is that if you want to leverage IAM for authorization (granting access to things) you need to use identity pool IDs (federated identities), but if you are going to handle authorization yourself in your application code and never let users access AWS resources directly, and not let users log in through other authentication mechanisms, then using user pool IDs makes more sense.

Answer (score 3):

You can think of it this way: User Pool provides a login method (i.e. an authentication method).

Whereas Identity Pool provides a way to create a user identity based on a single or multiple login methods (e.g. Facebook login, Google login, Cognito User Pool login), and in turn, create IAM permissions tied to that identity. It's more about Authorization - what a user with this identity can do.

That said, you can still perform Authorization using just User Pool User Ids. You just have to write the custom logic yourself based on the information about that user stored under User Pool Attributes (e.g. their email or name), to allow or deny them access to certain books.

If you eventually want to enable the user to use multiple sources of logins (e.g. Facebook login, Google login, AWS Cognito login), then consider using Identity Pool user id.

In most cases, if you make users login via an app and access the resources (books in this case) via the app, storing the User Pool User Id makes things easier. Cognito generates a secure User Pool User IdToken which contains the User Id on login. The app can just pass this token along with the request for your backend to allow/ deny the request.

Answer (score 0):

User pools stores the user records while identity pool has the necessary permissions available for the user. So in this case you need to use user pool Id